# When to use Socket and when to use XMLSocket in Flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3, sockets

In what situations should i use Socket class or XMLSocket when trying to connect from Flex to a Java Server that is going to listen to a port?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is rather simple:
An XMLSocket will send/receive XML data while a Socket will send/receive binary data

Check out [the adobe livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_5.html) for more information

Cheers